# UITableView is displayed half of the screen after converting to Universal app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I want to convert an iphone app to universal. the iphone storyboard has a UITableView. I used Auto-layout and Use Size Classes using the latest XCode and added missing constraints however I cannot make the tableView and its cells go all the way down; it's only half way of the screen. Can anyone have an idea on how to do this; Thank you very much. I attached the screenshot here:

[[image: screenshot]]

Comment: This sounds like a bug with your auto layout constraints. Can you paste a screenshot of that?

Comment: post a screenshot of your view controller in the storyboard with the constraints as well

Comment: just added a screenshot, don't mind the ad ; I fixed the size for the ad but not for the UITableView